# What weak, or weakest, conditions ensure the existence of two intervals such that a function is uniformly larger on one than the other

Tags: real-analysis, piecewise-continuity

What weak or weakest conditions (on the function and its domain) ensure that a real-valued, not essentially constant function on a real domain has the property that for any y between the functions essential infimum and essential supremum, there exist a pair of disjoint intervals such that the function is larger than y on one and less than y on the other. Piecewise continuity is sufficient.  But perhaps there are weaker conditions.

Comment: Why is not essentially constant necessary? It seems that the claim is vacuously true for these

Comment: I see what you mean.  I will add "not essentially constant" to the original statement.